# Trying to find proper Open source CAD Software For the Automatic Tooth Comparing

Tags: cad, software

I am trying to do the Automatic Tooth's CAD Compare for Tooth crowns preparation. One software for this work is the [**PrepCheck** software](https://www.dentsplysirona.com/en/explore/universities-and-large-clinics/products/prepcheck.html) and do it like shown below (YouTube video)][6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qE9ArjjKIF0)

[image]

So it must be done by on the 32 Constant Geometrical characteristic for the teeth as said [here](https://www.dentistry.umn.edu/sites/dentistry.umn.edu/files/module_on_crown_preparation.pdf).

If **possible**, I am asking about finding the **best Open source CAD compare Software** to do this automatic calculation?

I guess the [**CloudCompare**](https://www.danielgm.net/cc/) could be a **candidate**, For doing it. For this, it needs to write some scripts for:

1. Finding every one of 32 tooth locations by [**Artificial
   intelligence CAD Segmentation**](https://www.google.com/search?q=cad%20segmentations%20site%3Acolab.research.google.com&oq=cad%20segmentations%20site%3Acolab.research.google.com&aqs=chrome..69i57.18579j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) (like said [here](https://medium.com/autodesk-university/autonomous-geometry-processing-using-machine-learning-and-forge-3b89b40e97cb) and
   [here](https://github.com/timzhang642/3D-Machine-Learning)) or ...,
2. Doing **the compare** by some **automatic scripts for that location** in
   STL file.

So, **The** **question** is for **finding the proper software to do this procedure on it** (blender or  ...), by finding some **popular Open source CAD software** for this calculation I could find some **sample codes** via [GitHub](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:https://github.com/%20stl%20file%20compare%20ai&sxsrf=ALeKk01FUx3jh7sFG3dB64uNb_5S9xVyXQ:1615679641575&source=lnms&tbm=isch) and [Paperswithcode](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:https://paperswithcode.com/%20stl%20file%20compare%20ai&sxsrf=ALeKk01wimK5O0QgbOALxyxFECIb7BaelA:1615679013620&source=lnms&tbm=isch#imgrc=4qx73pbhnG6S_M) site, **better**.

**Note**:

Excuse me, If having too much information. This is because, I have tried to ask this question as a **guideline** to do this project, for myself or others (by adding the search links and ...),

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like a resource hunting question and I seem to have read the same thing before but, oddly, they no longer exist, see https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10/10902

Comment: This looks like a [resource-hunting question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832). Such questions are prone to becoming out-dated, and are therefore considered off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 3):

This question may be better suited for the software recommendation SE and perhaps could be migrated.

Consider that [Meshlab](https://www.meshlab.net/) meets a couple of your requirements. It's open source and has a comparison capability:

> Measuring the geometric difference between two 3D models using
> Hausdorff Distance is a common approach in mesh processing. Many years
> ago (in 1997!), the Visual Computing Lab developed and freely
> distributed what become the standard tool for such task, Metro; the
> related paper has been cited more than one thousand times. While the
> original Metro tool was a small open source standalone command line
> program (still available at our web site), MeshLab offers now much
> more advanced functionalities for comparing two meshes, that also
> compute signed distance and may work on point clouds.

Text and image from linked site.

[image: comparing mesh image]